# How to indicate to nextlow where takes output?

Tags: nextflow

I have a script in python which save a file in a specific directory.

For example this code named "write.py":

```
with open("project/results/txt/output.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("this is a txt file")
```

So I execute my script in "project/src" and the output of this script is in "project/results/txt/".

Here an example of a script Nextflow in "project/":

```
process writeTxt{
    output:
    file "output.txt"

    """
    python3 ../../../src/write.py 
    """
}
```

"../../../"  ==> to go out of work directory

But nextflow return that it didn't find "projet/results/txt/output.txt".

So how indicates to Nextflow where is the output of a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an anti-pattern. Nextflow tasks are expected to produce and consume files in task execution directory. If such output file is produced by a upstream task, that must be declared as task output to make it accessible in the task work directory.

Comment: How Can I declare this? I don't know the way to do that.

Comment: because I started Nextflow last week.